# Iphone-sdk - "can not use an object as parameter to a method"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

my .h file is as follows

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}
- (void) addWidget: (Widget*)aWidget;
@end
```

For sake of example, Widget is just some simple class that only holds a couple of strings.  Apparently, either i'm doing something wrong or am just spoiled by Java / C# because when I try building, the compiler tells me that i can't use an object as a parameter to a method.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Or do objective-c methods not accept complex types?  (say it ain't so!)

**[UPDATE]**
Ok this is odd..  but I just selected "clean" from the Build menu and now the error went away..  ah.. such misdirection on my part.

Comment: It ain't so! See Chuck's answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing wrong with that code is that Widget isn't declared anywhere. You should either `#import "Widget.h"` or put `@class Widget;` before the type is used.